# Python: struct.pack and struct.unpack for NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, struct

I am exploring NumPy version of `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack`. My particular problem is converting an RGB value `(r, g, b)` into a binary.

For example:

```
f = lambda r, g, b: struct.unpack('I', struct.pack('BBBB', r, g, b, 255))[0]
f(155, 156, 148)
#--> 4287929499
```

When I apply this conversion to an image (2-d array of RGB), it becomes very slow.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import struct

img_rgb = np.random.randint(0, 256, (480, 640, 3))
%%time
np.apply_along_axis(lambda rgb: struct.unpack('I', struct.pack('BBBB', rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], 255))[0], 2, img_rgb)
#--> Wall time: 5.23 s
```

My question is that is there NumPy version of `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack`? Or, how can I make this code faster with NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need [`pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) and [`unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) operations in numpy because it uses raw binary arrays instead of individually wrapping each value in a separate object. In general, the operations you use are [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), [`ndarray.view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html), and sometimes [`ndarray.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

In your particular case, you have and `(M, N, 3)` image, which you want to add a channel of 255 to and convert to [`np.uint8`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.uint8):

```
img_rgb = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(480, 640, 3))
img_rgba = np.concatenate((img_rgb.astype(np.uint8), np.full((*img_rgb.shape[:-1], 1), 255, dtype=np.uint8)), axis=-1)
```

By setting the last dimension to size 4, you ensure that you can now view the data directly as [`np.uint32`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.uint32):

```
result = img_rgba.view(np.uint32)
```

The result will be of shape `(M, N, 1)`. You can remove the extra dimension with [`np.squeeze`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
result = np.squeeze(img_rgba.view(np.uint32))
```

This doesn't really buy you much: it removes the convenient 3-channel representation without altering the memory layout. Dumping either `img_rgba` or `result` to a raw binary file would produce identical results.

In general, functions like [`apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) are generally code-smell in numpy. They are no better than running an explicit `for`-loop. Your goal should always be to vectorize your code to perform operations on all elements at once.

Comment: Great! This way improved the computation speed 150 times.